# MongoServerError: The $v update field is only recognized internally during restoring from logs

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, pymongo

I accidently deleted all the records from a collection. Found a reference [here](https://www.mongodb.com/community/forums/t/recover-deleted-documents/126094/3) and tried doing the same. It worked fine for inserted documents. But while trying to retrieve the updated records, i get the following error:

```
MongoServerError: The $v update field is only recognized internally
```

The following command worked fine while retreiving the inserted documents:

```
db.oplog.rs.aggregate([
    {$match: {op: 'i', ns: 'mydb.mycol'}},
    {$replaceRoot: {newRoot: '$o'}}, 
    {$merge: { into: {db: "mydb", coll: "mycol1"}, on: "_id", whenMatched: "replace", whenNotMatched: "insert" } }
])
```

While trying to get the updated ones, using the following command:

```
db.oplog.rs.find({op: 'u', ns: 'mydb.mycol'}, {o:1})
```

I get the following:

```
{
  o: {
    '$v': 1,
    '$set': {
      annotations: [
        {
          type: 'box',
          x: 0.5420038870967743,
          y: 0.5811289583333333,
          w: 0.15928567741935484,
          h: 0.05266285714285712,
          highlighted: true,
          editingLabels: false,
          color: '#4caf50',
          cls: 'SIGN',
          id: '7756483065364255'
        }
      ],
      updated_time: 2023-04-03T06:13:23.884Z
    }
  }
}
{
  o: {
    '$v': 1,
    '$set': {
      annotations: [
        {
          type: 'box',
          x: 0.5420038870967743,
          y: 0.5811289583333333,
          w: 0.15928567741935484,
          h: 0.05266285714285712,
          highlighted: true,
          editingLabels: false,
          color: '#4caf50',
          cls: 'LOGO',
          id: '7756483065364255'
        }
      ],
      updated_time: 2023-04-03T06:13:23.884Z
    }
  }
}
...
...
```

Now when trying to recover the updated ones, i am getting the following error:

```
MongoServerError: The $v update field is only recognized internally
```

The following is the command that i run:

```
db.oplog.rs.aggregate([
  {$match: {op: 'u', ns: 'mydb.mycol'}},
  {$replaceRoot: {newRoot: '$o'}}, 
  {$merge: { into: {db: "mydb", coll: "mycol2"}, on: "_id", whenMatched: "replace", whenNotMatched: "insert" } }
])
```

How to recover the records that were updated?

Kindly advise. Thank you.

Comment: What other fields are returned with `db.oplog.rs.find({op: 'u', ns: 'mydb.mycol'})`?